# Where can i find the serial number on engine for a Mercedes-Benz OM651?

Tags: engine, mercedes-benz, vin, c220

As the title says, I would like to know where I could find the serial number (or VIN) on the engine on a Mercedes-Benz C-Class C220 CDI W204 from 2012. The engine is the OM651. I am looking for it as I want to know if the engine is the original one. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I can find no specific information for your question, but after looking at the engine block i suggest 2 places to look on the block. Reference 2 red arrows in the image below. It may be difficult to impossible to see the engine serial number on that engine fully assembled and installed in the car.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to look for the serial number on those two places. I find it very weird that there is no information about these kind of things. I guess most people go with their cars at the dealer, so there isn't a large request for this information.